# Schema-agnostic OLAP-like tool?

Tags: sql, mdx, olap, pivot-table, xmla

Do there exist any (ideally free or open-source) tools for performing OLAP analyses on *arbitrary* tables in a relational database, without requiring any advance specification of dimensional hierarchies, cardinalities, or any other meta-information about the table beyond what can be extracted automatically from the table itself?

My inability to Google for anything like what I'm describing makes me suspect I'm using incorrect terminology and what I'm searching for isn't properly considered to be OLAP. If this is the case, what I specifically want is anything that would let technically unsophisticated users create cross-tab or contingency table aggregations using tables in a relational DB without needing to write elaborate SQL queries.

Or, in other words, I'd like something that mimics Excel's PivotTables on a larger scale. I appreciate that Excel does indeed generate extensive caches behind the scenes when you make a PivotTable, but it does this without the user having to explain to it which caches need creating. This is the functionality I'm trying to find elsewhere, if it exists.

Comment: What about LibreOffice Calc DataPilot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best options I know of are Excel and Access, but of course they are not open source. This space kinda got trampled in the explosion of interest in what is now called Business Intelligence and a lot of companies got bought by MS and others. It's pretty thin now as far as I can tell. I'll watch this thread though.

The most useful paradigm to attach to is I think spreadsheets and there's not much competition there any more. Google Docs spreadsheets can import csv etc. exported from databases, and there's a pivot chart available, but not much more.

The other place I've seen OLAP capabilities is in the Adobe Flex libraries to build on with ActionScript if you have any inclination in that direction. As usual, Adobe manages to get it about 90% right but doesn't quite provide a whole product.

Answer (score 0):

[icCube](http://www.icCube.com) aims to setup an OLAP cube as simply as possible. It is not schema-agnostic, but I guess this is quite simple to define dimensions and facts from existing DB tables. Nevertheless, this could be not so "simple" depending on your tables - difficult to say without knowledge about them. I guess there's no generic easy solution ;-)

Then you can use Excel pivot table (amongst others) to access the cubes. Note as far as I know Excel does not do any caching neither aggregation when connecting to a cube. Indeed, it is generating all the required MDX requests to the cube.

Hope that helps.